# Escuchar las actualizaciones de datos consumiento API Restfull desde Angular 5

Tags: angular5, restful, http-get

Soy nuevo en Angular, para explicarme adecuadamente voy apartir de un ejemplo.

Cuando tenemos instalada la librería de Firebase en nuestro proyecto podemos hacer el llamado de la información de la tabla **Users** de la siguiente manera:

```
constructor(db:AngularFirestore){
db.collection('Users').valueChanges().subscribe((data: User[]) => {
  this.users= data;
  console.log(this.users);
 });
}
```

el método **valueChanges()** se encarga de escuchar cualquier cambio de la base de datos y actualizarlos en la vista de usuario sin necesidad de refrescarla (esto al hacer un cambio manual sobre un determinado campo en la misma base de datos de Firebase).

Entonces, ¿De que manera se puede lograr este resultado, si por ejemplo estoy consumiendo un API Rest? Si al hacer un cambio directo en la base de datos este cambio se vea reflejada en la vista del usuario sin la necesidad de refrescar.

```
// users.service.ts
get():Observable<any>{
   return this.httpClient.get(this.API_ENDPOINT+'/users_location');
}

// user.component.ts
users: Users[]=[];
constructor(private userService: UsersService) {
   this.getTrailers();
}

getUsers(){
  this.userService.get().subscribe( (data:Users[])=>{
    this.users= data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Bueno Firebase tiene realtime database por lo que cada vez que se actualiza un objeto en la base de datos puede avisar a todos los clientes conectados. Si puedes modificar el back podrías hacer lo mismo usando socket.io o signalR, ya que tendrías que ser tú el que detecte cuando se ha modificado y avisar a todos los clientes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro cómo está implementado valueChanges(), si crea un webSocket para recibir notificaciones *push* o simplemente se hace una llamada AJAX cada X segundos, pero si tienes una API REST, el camino es la segunda opción:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
const TIME=5000; //milisegundos
export class UserService {

  ...

  get():Observable<User[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.API_ENDPOINT+'/users_location');
  }

  pollUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return timer(0,TIME).switchMap(() => this.get());
    }
}
```

Lo que hace este código: el método `pollUsers` devuelve un observable que cada 5 segundos hará una llamada AJAX al servidor y emitirá la respuesta. Este es un ejemplo que demuestra la potencia de los Observables respecto a las promesas: el observable sigue funcionando hasta que hagamos un `unsuscribe`, de manera periódica seguirá emitiendo datos sin que tengamos que hacer nada más.

La función `timer(X,TIME)` hace lo siguiente: emite una secuencia de números, empezando por 0. Lo hace cada `TIME` milisegundos, esperando `X` milisegundos para la primera emisión. Como ese valor no nos sirve para nada, con `switchMap` lo cambiamos por otra cosa: el resultado de llamar a `this.get()`.

PS: REST y WebSockets no son excluyentes, REST es un estilo arquitectural, no una tecnología. Nada te impide tener una URL *RESTful* que permitiese una conexión mediante el protocolo WebSocket para que sea el servidor el que emita los cambios en tiempo real. Mi solución asume que no quieres/puedes cambiar el API de back-end

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo Lozano! ya he solucionado mi problema.